# Declaração de forma dinâmica em JAVA

Tags: java, instanciar-objeto

Estou fazendo um trabalho sobre grafos e preciso ler no arquivo a entrada dos dados de um arquivo, exemplo :

VERTICES
0 1 2 3 4

ARESTAS
0 1
2 3

Depois de ler o arquivo preciso instanciar esses vértices e arestas, gostaria de saber uma forma pela qual eu possa instanciar dinamicamente, ou seja criar um numero de instancias de acordo com o numero de vértices e arestas que foram lidas do arquivo e depois adiciona-los em uma lista.

Sou novo em programação e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso e como eu faço, ou se ha um algum método melhor para esse objetivo.

Answer (score 1):

Isso carregaria um arquivo texto do tipo:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

Onde `1 2 3 4` seria as coordenadas pegas uma de cada vez:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:/suasCordenadas.txt"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

Caso queira algo do tipo `1,2,3,4` direto terá que aprender a mexer com `String` localizar cada virgula e pegar o numero a esquerda da virgula, não tendo mais virgulas pegar o ultimo algarismo.

Outras tecnicas seria aprender a sintaxe do xml e criar suas próprias tags exemplo: `<Vertice> 1,2,3,4 </Vertice>` ou expressão regulares também dá para criar suas tags.

Por fim `Serializable` onde você cria um editor salva um arquivo binário que pode ser reaberto e editado e depois é interpretado pelo seu programa. Mas isso já é nível intermediário

Comment: Boa tarde, não use o stacksnippet pra códigos que não podem ser executados, leia pra entender como funciona: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/3635 . Tenho certeza que vai levar meu comentário como um critica construtiva :)

Answer (score 0):

Toda List em Java possui um método chamado add() que serve para adicionar novos elementos. Não precisa declarar previamente quantos serão, já que ela cresce dinamicamente. Não entendi exatamente como estão representados os seus dados, mas, uma vez que você já possui o dado, basta fazer minhaLista.add(meuDado).